# Apache Airflow pools: used slots > available slots

Tags: airflow

I have 6 subdags. Each of them contains a task with `pool='crawler'` that requires a lot of resources so I created a pool `crawler` with only 1 slot.

When I run the DAG it seems that the pool restriction is bypassed and all six tasks are executed at the same time (as you can see from the screenshot).

How can I force used slots to be `<=` available slots?

[image: airflow pools]

Comment: Looks like an Airflow bug and I wonder if it's related to you using subdags. Just to clarify, you only set the pool on a single task within the subdag right? Meaning the actual `SubDagOperator` in the "parent" DAG itself does not have a pool limit?

Comment: Yes right @DanielHuang, the `SubDagOperator` doesn't have a pool. Only one of its "child task" has pool limit

Comment: Got it. Subdags are implemented by having the SubDagOperator kickoff the child DAG as a backfill job. I believe there are known issues with backfills adhering to concurrency and pool restrictions. A workaround could be to give the `SubDagOperator` the pool parameter instead, but it's not ideal since you lose some granularity (other tasks in the subdag are now stuck waiting). Alternatively, you can stop using subdag and move the shared code into a helper instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [source code](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/848e432865da82c86918bac8b466d17dc12cd84c/airflow/operators/subdag_operator.py#L94-L96):

> Airflow pool is not honored by SubDagOperator. Hence resources could
>   be consumed by SubdagOperators

Comment: So there is no hope to use `SubDagOperator` + pools for now. Thank you.
I assigned the pool to the `SubDagOperator`s instead of assigning it to internal tasks. It is not the desired behavior but it is a temporary solution.

Comment: kaxil this comment should be also in the Pool section of the docs https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#pools   it's very important and it's unlikely that users will read it in the source code

Comment: @Luis agreed - will add it.